# How to get back to previous route state in angularjs

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I have an angular app with a few routes. on one of them there is a jquery plugin (bxslider) that I'm activating on viewContentLoaded. 
If I go to a different route and then come back all the jQuery manipulation I did on the rout's view is cleared and I need to do it over again?

Is there a way to come back to a previous route in its last state (with the query plugin already rendered?

```
angTestApp.controller('MyRouteCtrl', function($scope, $timeout) {
  $scope.readyFunction = function(e) {
    $timeout(function(){
      $('.slider').bxSlider();
    });
//

 }
$scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', $scope.readyFunction);
});
```

Each time a call the route MyRoute the slider is re-rendered is there any way I can get the rendered version if I already been in that URL before and I'm still currently in the app (but in a different route)? (After all its a hash tag view and the browser shouldn't refresh inside the app)

Comment: Show us the revelant code.

Comment: Added code sample in above

Comment: the way to do it is to have the state saved in the controller, and build the page using the controller as usual.

Comment: Hey Gav, how did you solved the problem with the bxSlider? I have the same problem and I'm stuck because I'm using ng-repeat for the images and the slider successfully applies to the wrapper and to the element but not the images. Can you show me your code?

Comment: My code is scattered all around  - create a jsfiddle and I'll check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I go to a different route and then come back all the jQuery manipulation I did on the route's view is cleared and I need to do it over again?

Yes:

> Every time the current route changes, the included view changes with it according to the configuration of the $route service. -- [ng-view docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angView)

.

> Is there a way to come back to a previous route in its last state (with the query plugin already rendered?

Not with normal ng-view and routing.  When you first leave the route with the bxSlider, the DOM elements inside the ng-view are replaced with the DOM elements associated with the new view.

Maybe when you leave the view with the bxSlider you could "jQuery move" it to some hidden DOM element somewhere on the page (e.g., in some footer area), then move it back when you go back to the route.  I think the bottom line is that you'll have to "cache" it yourself somewhere, and restore it yourself.  Wrapping the code and data in an Angular service would probably be best.

Comment: Thanks I'll try it and let you know

Comment: When trying this method a strange thing happens - the DOM gets to the previous state but the slider is not responsive anymore - I'm not sure this behavior realtes to Angular - for example you can reproduce what I'm doing simply using the console ->

`var clonedSlider = $('.slider').clone();
$('.slider').detach();
$('.sliderContainer').html(clonedSlider);`

Comment: Just guessing here: "any event handlers bound to the original element are not copied to the clone. The optional withDataAndEvents parameter allows us to change this behavior, and to instead make copies of all of the event handlers as well, bound to the new copy of the element." -- http://api.jquery.com/clone/

Comment: Nice one adding TRUE to clone() fixed it. I'm steal thinking that it feels like a hack - I wish there was an ng-view or route property to tell angular to cache the view state instead of me trying to manipulate the DOM

Comment: Well, ng-view is just a simple page/view-changer.  If you had to implement your desired operation with only jQuery you'd probably have a bunch of "page" divs that you would hide/show based on a route or a tab click.  You can do that with Angular if you want, instead of using ng-view (and then you wouldn't have to move/clone things).  The homepage has a nice tabs-pane example that uses directives and hide/show instead of ng-view.